# How to Optimize PostgresqlSQL Query which contain INNER JOIN

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-10

I am trying to create a view which contain Suspicious order from a orders table.
The condition for the suspicious order is, every new order(in an interval), which have "New Customer" tag and used the discount codes(`_sdc_sequence`) from a table `orders__discount_codes` and either zip code or phone number of customer is matching in previous to that interval.
My attempt is

1. Created a view which contain all old orders(previous to the interval of 2 days) with "new customer tag"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema.old_orders_view AS
SELECT odr.id, odr.customer__id,odr.name, odr.billing_address__phone, odr.shipping_address__zip,odr.order_number, odr.updated_at 
FROM schema.orders odr, schema.orders__discount_codes odc
WHERE odr._sdc_sequence=odc._sdc_sequence 
AND
odr.updated_at<now() - interval '2 day' 
AND  
odr.tags LIKE'%New Customer%' 
AND 
odr.cancelled_at is null
AND
odr.confirmed ='t';
```

2. Created a view containing new orders(within the period 2 days)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema.new_orders_view AS
SELECT odr.id, odr.customer__id,odr.name, odr.billing_address__phone, odr.shipping_address__zip,odr.order_number, odr.updated_at 
FROM schema.orders odr, schema.orders__discount_codes odc
WHERE odr._sdc_sequence=odc._sdc_sequence 
AND
odr.updated_at>=now() - interval '2 day' 
AND  
odr.tags LIKE'%New Customer%' 
AND 
odr.cancelled_at is null
AND
odr. confirmed ='t';
```

3. later inner joined them

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema.suspicious_orders_view AS
SELECT n_odr.customer__id new_customer__id,n_odr.name new_name,o_odr.customer__id old_customer__id,o_odr.name old_name,o_odr.updated_at old_updated_at,n_odr.updated_at new_updated_at, o_odr.id old_id, n_odr.id new_id          
FROM
schema.new_orders_view n_odr, schema.old_orders_view o_odr
WHERE
o_odr.billing_address__phone=n_odr.billing_address__phone
OR
o_odr.shipping_address__zip=n_odr.shipping_address__zip;
```

What I need is the third View( `suspicious_orders_view` 
).

Is there any way to optimize these queries? The table contain more than one 100K records. every day there is  50- 100 new records in `new_orders_view`
If the query is without two dummy view is more good (If it is not possible to optimize doing this also great).

I have used this in my application and tring to connect with `google data studio`
got error

ERROR:

```
Unable to Connect Host: An I/O error occurred  while  sending to the backed.
```

So, optimizing the query will be more appropriate.

I am using Postgresql 10.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider changing your inner join to a subquery (so as not to return duplicate results), and consider adding indexes for performance. If you want us to be able to help you more than that, please give us the explain plan of the slow query.

Comment: Curious if you can normalize your _tags_ data.  `LIKE'%New Customer%'` is gonna amount to a full table scan every time..

Comment: @MikeChristensen there is no way to change `LIKE'%New Customer%`

Comment: @TamirIlan  how to change inner join to a subquery? I hope it will help?